# Getting composable from NavDestination

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've got the following code:

`BottomNavigationBar`

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavController, items: List<BottomNavigationItem>, selectedItemIndex: Int) {
    val currentDestination = navController.currentDestination?.route
    var showNavBar = currentDestination?.let { route ->
        items.any { it.route == route }
    } ?: false

    items.forEach { item ->
        if(currentDestination == item.route) showNavBar = true
    }

    if(showNavBar) {
        NavigationBar {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                NavigationBarItem(
                    selected = selectedItemIndex == index,
                    onClick = { navController.navigate(item.route) },
                    label = { Text(text = item.title) },
                    icon = {
                        BadgedBox(
                            badge = {
                                if(item.badgeCount != null) {
                                    if(item.badgeCount != 0) {
                                        Text(text = item.badgeCount.toString())
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = if(index == selectedItemIndex) item.selectedIcon else item.unselectedIcon,
                                contentDescription = item.title
                            )
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

data class BottomNavigationItem(
    val title: String,
    val route: String,
    val selectedIcon: ImageVector,
    val unselectedIcon: ImageVector,
    val badgeCount: Int? = null,
)
```

And this is what I have in terms of my app class so far:

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AppView() {

    val navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = NavigationDestination.RecentsView.route
    ) {
        composable(route = NavigationDestination.RecentsView.route) {
            RecentsView()
        }
        composable(route = NavigationDestination.FavouritesView.route) {
            FavouritesView()
        }
        composable(route = NavigationDestination.DialerView.route) {
            DialerView()
        }
        composable(route = NavigationDestination.ContactsView.route) {
            ContactsView()
        }
        composable(route = NavigationDestination.AddContactView.route) {
            AddContactView()
        }
    }

    val items = listOf(
        BottomNavigationItem(
            title = stringResource(R.string.title_favourites),
            route = NavigationDestination.FavouritesView.route,
            selectedIcon = Icons.Filled.Favorite,
            unselectedIcon = Icons.Outlined.FavoriteBorder,
        ),
        BottomNavigationItem(
            title = stringResource(R.string.title_dialer),
            route = NavigationDestination.DialerView.route,
            selectedIcon = Icons.Filled.Phone,
            unselectedIcon = Icons.Outlined.Phone,
        ),
        BottomNavigationItem(
            title = stringResource(R.string.title_recents),
            route = NavigationDestination.RecentsView.route,
            selectedIcon = Icons.Filled.Alarm,
            unselectedIcon = Icons.Outlined.Alarm,
            badgeCount = 0
        ),
        BottomNavigationItem(
            title = stringResource(R.string.title_contacts),
            route = NavigationDestination.ContactsView.route,
            selectedIcon = Icons.Filled.Person,
            unselectedIcon = Icons.Outlined.Person,
        )
    )

    var selectedItemIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(2) } // This needs to match the items list of the page selected.

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigationBar(
                navController = navController,
                items = items,
                selectedItemIndex = selectedItemIndex
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .fillMaxSize(),

        ) {
            // I need to display the composable here
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this should be a simple bottom navigation bar for a few of my "master" views and then when I need to hide the bar, it should.

What I cannot figure out is how to display the current view that is selected.

I figured I would be able to just get the `navController.currentDestination?.getComposable()` or something to that effect, however, this does not exist. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are still thinking too much in the View based UI.

There is no composable to get a hold on. Compose is UI based stricly on underlying data - if it does not show what you want it to - there is something missing in the data - or placement of the composables(which is I think your case).

```
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        BottomNavigationBar(
            navController = navController,
            items = items,
            selectedItemIndex = selectedItemIndex
        )
    }
) { innerPadding ->
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(innerPadding)
            .fillMaxSize(),

    ) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = NavigationDestination.RecentsView.route
        ) {
            composable(route = NavigationDestination.RecentsView.route) {
                RecentsView()
            }
            composable(route = NavigationDestination.FavouritesView.route) {
                FavouritesView()
            }
            composable(route = NavigationDestination.DialerView.route) {
                DialerView()
            }
            composable(route = NavigationDestination.ContactsView.route) {
                ContactsView()
            }
            composable(route = NavigationDestination.AddContactView.route) {
                AddContactView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do it that way and then do the following:

```val currentDestination = navController.currentDestination?.route``` it returns null because NavHost is populated after, so that doesn't work?

Comment: @JamieRhys You can listen to that as a state - added the snippet.